FullCalendar RRule Not Respecting DST When using ISO Formatted 'dstart' option
Please correct me if I am using the rrule plugin incorrectly.
FullCalendar Version 6.1.11 with rule plugin in React
The below pertains to recurring events only. I do not have an issue with normal events.
codepen: https://codepen.io/tcjens/pen/XWwbvQL?editors=001
     {
       title: 'rrule event',
        rrule: {
          dtstart: '2024-05-17T06:00:00.000Z', //2am Fridays EDT or 11PM Thursdays PDT
          freq: 'weekly',
          byweekday:['fr']
        },
        duration: '01:00'
      }

My backend stores all dates in UTC
Im on an air-gapped network. I am not able to share my code. But it's replicated in reduced form in the code pen.
Perhaps this is user error - but any help is highly appreciated!!!
When setting dtstart of an RRule for an event to an ISOString() formatted string with timezone, DST is not respected across the OCT 31 / NOV 1 barrier as seen in the code pen. However, differences in the 'by weekday' array across time zones are still respected.
For example, a recurring event at 2 AM on Fridays EDT is actually 11 PM on Thursdays PDT. When using ISOString() dtstart, this difference is observed, but not DST across OCT31/NOV1
However, if you set the dtstart without a timezone, DST is observed and reflected BUT the weekdays will not be adjusted according to timezone.
